# How to get multiple word click in a single label

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, delegates

I am new to swift and I want to get multiple clickable word and different tap gesture on each word

EX:- "Please read terms & condition and Privacy Policy Properly" I need to click on "terms & condition" and print("terms") and when clicked on "Privacy Policy " It should print("Privacy")

I tried some thing but not getting proper out put as expected

```
let txt = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelCreateAccount.text!)
        let range = (labelCreateAccount.text! as NSString).range(of: "Term & Condition")
        let range1 = (labelCreateAccount.text! as NSString).range(of: "Privacy Policy")
        
        txt.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red] , range: range)
        txt.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red] , range: range1)
        labelCreateAccount.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:range, action: #selector(LabelTapAccount)))

        labelCreateAccount.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:range 1, action: #selector(LabelTapAccount)))

        labelCreateAccount.attributedText = txt
        labelCreateAccount.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: I think the best way is to add two different labels and add interaction in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create extension UITapGestureRecognizer

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
        
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize
        
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                          y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: (locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x),
                                                     y: 0 );
        
        let lineModifier = Int(ceil(locationOfTouchInLabel.y / label.font.lineHeight)) - 1
        let rightMostFirstLinePoint = CGPoint(x: labelSize.width, y: 0)
        let charsPerLine = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: rightMostFirstLinePoint, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        let adjustedRange = indexOfCharacter + (lineModifier * charsPerLine)
        
        return NSLocationInRange(adjustedRange, targetRange)
    }
    
}

extension Range where Bound == String.Index {
    var nsRange: NSRange {
        return NSRange(location: self.lowerBound.encodedOffset,
                       length: self.upperBound.encodedOffset -
                        self.lowerBound.encodedOffset)
    }
}
```

add TapGesture to target Label and on listener, check tapped on target string from attributedText:

```
@objc private func settingTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let range = self.yourLabel.text?.range(of: "your Text")?.nsRange else {
        return
    }
    
    if sender.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: self.yourLabel, inRange: range) {
        // your work
    }
    
}
```

now set Tap on Label:

```
let txt = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelCreateAccount.text!)
            let range = (labelCreateAccount.text! as NSString).range(of: "Term & Condition")
            let range1 = (labelCreateAccount.text! as NSString).range(of: "Privacy Policy")
            
            txt.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red] , range: range)
            txt.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red] , range: range1)

            labelCreateAccount.attributedText = txt
            
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(self.settingTapped(_:)))
            self.labelCreateAccount.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            self.labelCreateAccount.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: I already saw this but not able to understand this

Comment: can you help me understand this..?

Comment: yeah, first you create attributeText for show on Your Label then you add TapGesture on Label now you find position from tap gesture included your text for call any action

Comment: my biggest confusion is that where your I place this settingTaped functionalists

Comment: for last work, we create extension for UITapGestureRecognizer To find out exactly where it was touched and find range link Text with  range(of: _) function

Comment: edited my code for get listener TapGesture look again

Comment: guard let range = self.yourLabel.text?.range(of: "Account")?. *^here*nsRange else {
            return
        }

Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: please add extension for extension Range

Comment: ERROR: Value of type 'Range<String.Index>' has no member 'Range'

Comment: you implement extension Range where Bound == String.Index {
    var nsRange: NSRange {
        return NSRange(location: self.lowerBound.encodedOffset,
                       length: self.upperBound.encodedOffset -
                        self.lowerBound.encodedOffset)
    }
}

Comment: please send your email, to attach my complete code for you

Comment: I send my code for your email. check email.